# Reopen iOS app to specified navigation controller from AppDelegate using Swift2

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm working on an iOS Project using Swift.  I have a `ViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I have my app associated with `PDF` files in `plist`.  The user can open a `PDF` emailed to them in the project.  I know this then deals with:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    if url != "" {

        // Load from Mail App

        incomingFileTransfer = url

        incomingStatus = "Incoming"

        /*let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenu") as! MainMenuViewController
        rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToViewController(setViewController, animated: false)*/

    } else {

        // Regular Load

        print("App Delegate: No incoming file")

        incomingFileTransfer = nil

    }  

    return true
}
```

If the user is in another area of the app, and they open the app again from the `PDF`, the app opens back to the area where they were.  I want it to open to the first loaded `ViewController` always.  I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638376/get-instance-of-viewcontroller-from-appdelegate-in-swift) and tried to implement this in my section above in `AppDelegate` with no luck.  Can someone please help with this particularly in Swift? I'm not real great with converting Objective-C to Swift.

My `ViewController` has a `Title` set as `MainMenu`:

[image]

This `ViewController` has the `UINavigationController` set as the `Initial View` and a name of `Main`:

[image]

The `Storyboard` has a `Storyboard ID` of `Main` within the `UINavigationController` `Identity Inspector`:

[image]

**Update**:

Sorry. The `url` is assigned to a Global `Variable` that is then loaded into another `ViewController` that has a `WebView`.

Comment: *tried to implement this with no luck* The system gave you a URL and you didn't do anything with it, or remove any pushed view controllers from the navigation controller stack.  Where did you open the URL, or get your navigation controller's initial view controller to display the PDF?

Comment: Sorry.  Please see update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329999/restart-iphone-application-from-the-very-beginning This post should do what you're looking for.

Comment: What would happen if you uncommented the code?  And is the code doing anything specific with the URL?  How is the initial view controller supposed to know what PDF to display?

Comment: Uncommenting the code does nothing.  I tried unsuccessfully with it.

Comment: @NSGangster, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329999/restart-iphone-application-from-the-very-beginning) as @NSGangster suggested, I went into my `plist` and added the following:

[image]

Now my app re-opens as if it was the first time.